# How can I traverse binary search tree without recursion?

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-search-tree, traversal

I can traverse the binary search tree using recursion easily, but I don't have an idea about traverse without recursion so please anyone explain,.....

Comment: have you tried anything yourself at first. please post the codes where you are stuck.

Comment: You should probably read Wikipedia page on [Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) there are multiple algorithms there on how to do it with and without recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you can do it with stack. you have to take stack here the algorithm for p reorder, in-order and post-order traversal in iterative way (non recursive way/method) of binary search tree. Hope you will get properly.

**p re order:**

1) Create an empty stack node_Stack and push root node to stack.

2) Do following while node_Stack is not empty.

-> Pop an item from stack and print it.

-> Push right child of popped item to stack

-> Push left child of popped item to stack

**in-order:**

1) Create an empty stack S.

2) Initialize current node as root

3) Push the current node to S and set current = current->left until current is NULL

4) If current is NULL and stack is not empty then

```
 -> Pop the top item from stack.

 -> Print the popped item, set current = popped_item->right 

 -> Go to step 3.
```

5) If current is NULL and stack is empty then we are done.

**post-order:**

1.1 Create an empty stack

2.1 Do following while root is not NULL

```
-> Push root's right child and then root to stack.

-> Set root as root's left child.
```

2.2 Pop an item from stack and set it as root.

```
-> If the popped item has a right child and the right child 
   is at top of stack, then remove the right child from stack,
   push the root back and set root as root's right child.

-> Else print root's data and set root as NULL.
```

2.3 Repeat steps 2.1 and 2.2 while stack is not empty.