# AVL TREE traversal in order

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

Can someone help me, how I could traversal a balanced binary tree in order without recursion, stack, or morris traversal. I want to traverse it iteratively without modifying the tree.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I traverse binary search tree without recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022427/how-can-i-traverse-binary-search-tree-without-recursion)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no, it's not good because it uses the stack, and I want no stack, recursion and no tree modification

Comment: Is your tree threaded? Can you at least provide some code, and a data structure definition? Is "balanced" to be understood in the meaning of AVL trees, or do you have a *perfectly* balanced tree, like a *complete* binary tree?

Comment: Hello, the tree is perfectly balanced, and i want to traverse in order tree after is perfectly balanced

Comment: So, can you confirm it is a [*complete* binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)?

Comment: Yes, confirm, only i want, is to see to do traversal inorder, without recursion, stack, morris traversal, beacause i have no idea, how to traversal the tree perfectly balanced without changing.
if it can be done recursively without changing the tree, it must be possible to do it iteratively

Comment: Are the keys strictly monotonic (no duplicates)?

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: Are there guaranteed to not be any duplicate keys, _ie_ does the tree represent a set (or map, database), that could be put into a hash without any loss of information (except order), or could there be duplicates (multiset)? _Ie_, can there be `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`, or this would cause a collision and there would just be `{1}`?

Comment: Man, is a simple avl tree balanced, for example 3, 4, 5, 7, 10 must be printed in order, without stack, without recursive, without morris traversal, you have an ideea with the code or no ?

Answer (score 1):

In the case where there are no duplicate keys, this corresponds to the tree representing a set (or map.) In that case, a backtracking approach will be `O(log n)` (AVL tree property) *per* key. One could get a faster run time by storing the nodes, (such as in recursion,) but often this is unfeasible.

- If `current` is not null, descend `next` with the `current` key as the target. Whenever the left is taken, first assign an `ancestor` (before descending.)
- There are three cases: `current` was null -> `next = root`; `current == next` has a right child, `next <- next.right`; or `next` does not have a right child, `next <- ancestor` (if it does not exist, finished.)
- In the first two cases, descend on the left until you hit a leaf.

I'll use [Wikipedia AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) article example, without the balance factors, (this will work on any binary tree, but one is not guaranteed performance.)

[image: AVL tree.]

| current | path | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | root J | C |
| C | ancestor D | D |
| D | ancestor F | F |
| F | right G | G |
| G | ancestor J | J |
| J | right P | N |
| N | ancestor L | L |
| L | ancestor P | P |
| P | right V | Q |
| Q | ancestor S | S |
| S | right U | U |
| U | ancestor V | V |
| V | right X | X |
| X | ancestor null | null |

If the tree can have duplicate entries, this might be said to be a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). In this case, this will not work because this relies on the keys being unique.